# How do I generate a list of b1 coefficients from simulations of a simple linear regression model?

Tags: r, statistics

Hi so I have to simulate the linear model: B0 + B1Xi + ei 100 times with sample sizes of 10. The parameters are given to me as ei~N(0,2^2), Xi~(0,1^2), B0 = 0.5, and B1 = 2. I need to extract the slope coefficient from each simulation. So far I have been able to get the coefficients of single simulations but when I try to use the r function coefficients for multiple simulations at once I get NULL returned. Here is my code so far:

```
b1sims = function(nrep = 10, b0 = 0.5, b1 = 2, sigma = 2){
  e<-rnorm(n, 0, 2)
  x<-rnorm(n, 0, 1)
  y<-0.5 + 2*x + e
  n = 10
  simdata = data.frame(x, y)
  b1fit = lm(y~x, data = simdata)
  b1fit
  }
coefficients(replicate(100, b1sims()))
```

Comment: You use `n` before it is defined. You need to fix your function. `replicate` should return a list, so probably `sapply(replicate(100, b1sims()), coef)` would do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
replicate(100, b1sims())[1,]
```

This will give you a list of the coefficients.

`replicate(100, b1sims())` will give you a matrix which includes all the parameters of each regression model

Comment: It is not wrong. It obviously returns a list of the intercept and coefficients which the OP can easily handle using any basic function such as `simplify2array`, for example: `replicate(100, b1sims())[1,] %>% simplify2array() %>% .[2,]`. That does the same as what you have there.

Answer (score 0):

```
#fix the function so it runs
b1sims = function(n = 10, b0 = 0.5, b1 = 2, sigma = 2){
  e<-rnorm(n, 0, 2)
  x<-rnorm(n, 0, 1)
  y<-0.5 + 2*x + e

  simdata = data.frame(x, y)
  b1fit = lm(y~x, data = simdata)
  b1fit
}

#create 100 models and loop over resulting list
#to extract coefficients
sapply(replicate(100, b1sims(), simplify = FALSE), coef)[2, ]
```